# When capturing screenshots of the desktop, why am I getting an out of memory exception after a few minutes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In `form1` designer I added a timer and first set it to 1000ms then I changed it to 100ms and then in 100ms after it was saving screenshots to the hard disk after some minutes I got exception out of memory.

Then I changed it to 500ms and then again out of memory after few minutes.

I think when it's 1000ms it's ok.

This is the class for the screenshots:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides functions to capture the entire screen, or a particular window, and save it to a file.
    /// </summary>
    public class ScreenCapture
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of the entire desktop
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Image CaptureScreen()
        {
            return CaptureWindow(User32.GetDesktopWindow());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of a specific window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">The handle to the window. (In windows forms, this is obtained by the Handle property)</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
        {
            // get te hDC of the target window
            IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
            // get the size
            User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
            User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
            int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
            int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
            // create a device context we can copy to
            IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
            // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
            // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
            IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
            // select the bitmap object
            IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
            // bitblt over
            GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
            // restore selection
            GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
            // clean up 
            GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
            User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

            // get a .NET image object for it
            Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
            // free up the Bitmap object
            GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

            return img;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Captures a screen shot of a specific window, and saves it to a file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle"></param>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        /// <param name="format"></param>
        public void CaptureWindowToFile(IntPtr handle, string filename, ImageFormat format)
        {
            Image img = CaptureWindow(handle);
            img.Save(filename, format);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Captures a screen shot of the entire desktop, and saves it to a file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        /// <param name="format"></param>
        public void CaptureScreenToFile(string filename, ImageFormat format)
        {
            Image img = CaptureScreen();
            img.Save(filename, format);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing Gdi32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class GDI32
        {

            public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020; // BitBlt dwRop parameter

            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
                int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
                int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
                int nHeight);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing User32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class User32
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct RECT
            {
                public int left;
                public int top;
                public int right;
                public int bottom;
            }

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);

        }


    }
}
```

And this is how i use it in form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int count;
        ScreenCapture sc;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            count = 0;
            sc = new ScreenCapture();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            sc.CaptureScreenToFile(@"c:\temp\screens3\" + count.ToString("D6") + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to keep saving the screenshots at 100ms or 500ms without getting out of memory ?

Comment: You're never calling `Dispose` on your image instances. You therefore have RAW image byte data sitting in memory taking up loads and loads of space - especially on higher resolutions. You may even have to force a garbage collection (unfortunately) depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you did a good job at cleaning up your unmanaged resources you still need to clean up your managed resources. `Image` is notorious for holding on to resources that does not put memory pressure on to the GC. This causes a garbage collection to not automatically happen as often as with "normal" classes.

Try disposing of your image objects:

```
    public void CaptureWindowToFile(IntPtr handle, string filename, ImageFormat format)
    {
        using(Image img = CaptureWindow(handle))
        {
            img.Save(filename, format);
        }
    }

    public void CaptureScreenToFile(string filename, ImageFormat format)
    {
        using(Image img = CaptureScreen())
        {
            img.Save(filename, format);
        }
    }
```